# Why is WASAPI so much slower than ASIO?

Tags: windows, asio, wasapi, rtaudio

I measured the round-trip latency of [`RtAudio` Duplex Mode example](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/duplex.html) by an oscillograph. The result on the average as blow,

ASIO 15ms

WASAPI 50ms

Why is WASAPI so much slower? All documents on the Internet says them have the same performance.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Compiler: VC2013

Comment: Did you use WASAPI [Exclusive-Mode Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/coreaudio/exclusive-mode-streams) for low latency targeting tests?

Comment: @RomanR. `RtAudio` is not supported Exclusive-Mode .

Comment: So it's RtAudio "slow" because it does not offer support for exclusive mode streams then.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you're using Windows 7. Give Windows 10 a try; this has [some latency improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/low-latency-audio)